# Reduce list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, reduce

As part of my journey into learning python I am implementing Bulls and Cows.
I have a working implementation that uses list comprehension but I figured it might be a nice solution to solve this using a generator and `reduce()`-ing the final result.

So I have my generator:

```
def bullsandcows(given, number):
    for i in range(given.__len__()):
        if given[i] == number[i]:
            yield (given[i], None)
        elif given[i] in number:
            yield (None, given[i])
```

And my reduce implementation:

```
(bulls, cows) = reduce(\
    lambda (bull, cow), (b, c): \
        (bull + 1, cow + 1), bullsandcows(given, number), (0, 0))
```

Where `given` is the user input and `number` is the randomly generated number for the user to guess.

As you can see, this is not exactly a working implementation, this will just return the counts of the `yield`ed tuples.

What I need is a replacement for `(bull + 1, cow + 1)`, I have no idea how to construct this.

- `number` is a randomly generated number, say: `1234`
- `given` is entered by the user, say: `8241`
- The result of `bullsandcows(given, number)` would be: `[('2', None), (None, '4'), (None, '1']`
- The result of the `reduce` should be: `(1, 2)`, which is the count of all non-`None` values of the first element and count of all non-`None` values of the second element

Comment: Don't use `.__len__()` when `len(given)` is clearer, and don't use a `range()` when you could use `zip()` instead.

Comment: You are right, fixed that. It doesn't *seem* to ignore the output of `bullsandcows`. The result is always a two-element tuple containing the number of results from the generator

Comment: You are ignoring the `(b, c)` tuple in your lambda.

Comment: That's correct and it's also exactly my problem :)

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the input is, and what output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the process correctly, you want to count what `bull`s are not `None`, and how many `cow`s are not `None`:

```
reduce(lambda (bcount, ccount), (b, c): (bcount + (b is not None), ccount + (c is not None)),
       bullsandcows(given, number), (0, 0))
```

This increments a counter only if the `bull` or `cow` value is not `None`. The test produces a boolean, which is a subclass of `int` with `False == 0` and `True == 1`; summing an integer and a boolean results in another integer.

Since you are feeding it non-empty strings, you could simplify it to:

```
reduce(lambda (bcount, ccount), (b, c): (bcount + bool(b), ccount + bool(c)),
       bullsandcows(given, number), (0, 0))
```

I'd rewrite `bullsandcows()` to:

```
def bullsandcows(given, number):
    given, number = map(str, (given, number))
    for g, n in zip(given, number):
        if g == n:
            yield (g, None)
        elif g in number:
            yield (None, g)
```

e.g. use `zip()` to pair up the digits of `given` and `number`.

Demo:

```
>>> def bullsandcows(given, number):
...     given, number = map(str, (given, number))
...     for g, n in zip(given, number):
...         if g == n:
...             yield (g, None)
...         elif g in number:
...             yield (None, g)
... 
>>> given, number = 8241, 1234
>>> list(bullsandcows(given, number))
[('2', None), (None, '4'), (None, '1')]
>>> reduce(lambda (bcount, ccount), (b, c): (bcount + bool(b), ccount + bool(c)),
...        bullsandcows(given, number), (0, 0))
(1, 2)
```

Note that unpacking in function arguments was removed from Python 3 and the `reduce()` built-in has been delegated to library function; your code is decidedly Python 2 only.

To make it work in Python 3 you need to import [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and adjust the lambda to not use unpacking:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda counts, bc: (counts[0] + bool(bc[0]), counts[1] + bool(bc[1])),
       bullsandcows(given, number), (0, 0))
```

Comment: `elif g in str(number):`

Comment: @mtadd: was getting to that. :-)

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem completely. I wish I could give you another up-vote for going the extra mile by explaining how and why I could improve my code